# Ext JS grid panel events

Tags: extjs

I am developing my first EXT js mvc application. I have a problem adding events listeners to my grid panel from controller class.

My question is why i am getting below error while adding event handlers through 'on' method using below code

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: 
    gridPanel.on is not a function
    at constructor.init
```

Relevant Code:

```
var gridPanel = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('userlist');
gridPanel.on('itemdblclick', this.editUser, gridPanel);
```

I am able to add handlers through a different method though but i am trying to figure out what is wrong with adding through 'on' method on grid panel reference. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

---

Here is my complete controller class

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Users', {
        extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

        views: ['user.List'],

        init: function() {

            var gridPanel = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('userlist');
            gridPanel.on('itemdblclick', this.editUser, gridPanel);
        },

        editUser: function() {
            console.log('User edit has begun..');
        }
}, function() {

});
```

And my grid panel class:

```
Ext.define('AM.view.user.List', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.userlist',   
    title: 'All Users',
    id: 'usergrid',

    initComponent: function() {

            this.store = {
                fields: ['name', 'email'],
                data  : [
                    {name: 'Ed',    email: 'ed@sencha.com'},
                    {name: 'Tommy', email: 'tommy@sencha.com'}
                ]
            };

            this.columns = [
                {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name',  flex: 1},
                {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1}
            ],

        this.callParent(arguments);

    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 3):

`Ext.ComponentQuery.query('userlist')` returns an array of found components - so you need to select the first item in the array to actually get your component:
`Ext.ComponentQuery.query('userlist')[0]`

The `Ext.first('userlist')` shorthand makes this simpler. (As @sceborati mentioned in the comments)

When you use component query you are querying by its xtype*

You have also specified an id in your component, which is OK if you will only have one instance on a page, (as soon as you have more than one - you should not use ids)
You can find components much quicker using `Ext.getCmp('componentid')` so `Ext.getCmp('userlist')` would also work for you.

All that being said, to make better use of ExtJs MVC capabilities, you could switch to using a ViewController, and then you don't need to do any lookups for your components at all:

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.userlist',
    editUser: function () {
        console.log('User edit has begun..');
    }
});

Ext.define('AM.view.user.List', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype: 'userlist',
    title: 'All Users',
    id: 'usergrid',
    controller: 'userlist',
    store: {
        fields: ['name', 'email'],
        data: [{
            name: 'Ed',
            email: 'ed@sencha.com'
        }, {
            name: 'Tommy',
            email: 'tommy@sencha.com'
        }]
    },
    columns: [{
        header: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        header: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 1
    }],
    listeners:{
        itemdblclick:'editUser'
    }
});
```

Notice the `alias` config added to controller, and the corresponding `controller` config on the view.

This means you can specify listeners just by providing the method name on the controller.

```
    listeners:{
        itemdblclick:'editUser'
    }
```

You may also notice I have moved your column and store configuration out of the initComponent method - your use of initComponent would work, but this method is much cleaner.

I have created a fiddle to demonstrate this updated code:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qvu

You also seem to be passing an extra function as a third argument when defining  your controller - you should remove this.

---

* you have used `alias:'widget.userlist'` which is the same as `xtype:'userlist'`

Comment: This resolved my issue. Also this is the best explanation of View Controller which i do not know, Thanks for coaching me.

Comment: Great - happy to help - remember to accept my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

The [query method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.ComponentQuery.html#method-query) on Ext.ComponentQuery returns an array of components. So you would need to provide an index, like:

```
var gridPanel = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('userlist')[0];
```

Comment: For ExtJS 6 there is the [Ext.first](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.html#method-first) shortland. So you can use _Ext.first('userlist')_.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen that before.